# Recycler View is not fetching the data from database also there is not any exception

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Recycler view is not fetching data from firebase realtime database the codes are attached of Adapter class and main activity class.

Main Activity Class:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<UsersItem> usersItemArrayList;
    UserRecyclerAdapter adapter;

    Button buttonAdd;

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

//        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Items");
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.itemLists);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        usersItemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new UserRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity2.this,usersItemArrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        buttonAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);

        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ViewDialogAdd viewDialogAdd = new ViewDialogAdd();
                viewDialogAdd.showDialog(MainActivity2.this);

            }
        });

        readData();
    }

    private void readData() {

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
//                usersItemArrayList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren()){
                    UsersItem users = dataSnapshot.getValue(UsersItem.class);
                    usersItemArrayList.add(users);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),UsersItem.class.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    public class ViewDialogAdd {
        public void showDialog(Context context){
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.update_popup);
            dialog.show();

            EditText itemName = dialog.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            EditText itemBoxQty = dialog.findViewById(R.id.itemBoxQty);
            EditText itemPrice = dialog.findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);

            Button buttonAdd = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

            buttonAdd.setText("ADD");

            buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String id = "item"+new Date().getTime();
                    String nameItem = itemName.getText().toString();
                    String itemQtyBox = itemBoxQty.getText().toString();
                    String priceItem = itemPrice.getText().toString();


                    if(nameItem.isEmpty() || itemQtyBox.isEmpty() || priceItem.isEmpty()){
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Please Enter All Data...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        databaseReference.child(id).setValue(new UsersItem(id,nameItem,itemQtyBox,priceItem));
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

ADAPTER CLASS:

```
public class UserRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<UsersItem> usersItemArrayList;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    public UserRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<UsersItem> usersItemArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.usersItemArrayList = usersItemArrayList;
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view  = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.items,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        UsersItem users = usersItemArrayList.get(position);
        holder.itemName.setText(users.getItemName());
        holder.itemBoxQty.setText(users.getItemBoxQty());
        holder.itemPrice.setText(users.getItemPrice());

        holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ViewDialogUpdate viewDialogUpdate = new ViewDialogUpdate();
                viewDialogUpdate.showDialog(context, users.getUserID(), users.getItemName(), users.getItemBoxQty(), users.getItemPrice());

            }
        });

        holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView itemName,itemPrice,itemBoxQty;
        Button btnEdit,btnDelete;
        RelativeLayout rv;




        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemNames);
            itemPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemPrices);
            itemBoxQty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemBoxQtys);
            btnDelete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDeletes);
            btnEdit= itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
            rv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv);
        }
    }

    public class ViewDialogUpdate {
        public void showDialog(Context context,String id, String Name,String BoxQty,String Price){
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.update_popup);

            EditText itemName = dialog.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            EditText itemBoxQty = dialog.findViewById(R.id.itemBoxQty);
            EditText itemPrice = dialog.findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);

            itemName.setText(Name);
            itemBoxQty.setText(BoxQty);
            itemPrice.setText(Price);

            Button buttonUpdate = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

            buttonUpdate.setText("UPDATE");

            buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String newnameItem = itemName.getText().toString();
                    String newitemQtyBox = itemBoxQty.getText().toString();
                    String newpriceItem = itemPrice.getText().toString();


                    if(Name.isEmpty() || BoxQty.isEmpty() || Price.isEmpty()){
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Please Enter All Data...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{

                        if(newnameItem.equals(Name) && newitemQtyBox.equals(BoxQty)&& newpriceItem.equals(Price)){
                            Toast.makeText(context,"You haven't change anything",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }else{
                            databaseReference.child("Items").child(id).setValue(new UsersItem(id,Name,BoxQty,Price));
                            Toast.makeText(context,"Item Updated Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

MY recycler view to show the value in database recycler view comes out to be empty.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted more than **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Besides that, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?